# Complex Logic Trouble in C

Tags: c, logic

I am having trouble thinking this following block of code out and making sure that it works.

I have three possible input words, call them A, B, and C.

```
    //The following if-else block sets the variables TextA, TextB, and TextC to the    appropriate Supply Types.
if(strcmp(word,TextB)!=0 && strcmp(word,TextC)!=0 && i==1 && strcmp("",TextB)!=0) {
     strcpy(TextA,word);
}
else if(strcmp(word,TextA)!=0 && strcmp(word,TextC)!=0 && i==1 && strcmp("",TextC)!=0) {
  strcpy(TextB,word);
}
else if(strcmp(word,TextB)!=0 && strcmp(word,TextA)!=0 && i==1) {
  strcpy(TextC,word);
}
```

What I want to have happen is that, if TextA has nothing in it (the first time around AKA when i=1; this is all in a loop) then write word to TextA.  However, if TextA does have something in it, write word to TextB.  And if TextB has something in it, set TextC to word.  I can recopy over the words to their proper location, again because there are only 3 options.

Comment: Put all the strcmp result into some variable please. The code is hardly readable like this. It will also help you figure out whether your logic is correct or not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pull them into a variable?

Comment: Something like `int wordEqualTextA = !strcmp(word, textA);`

Comment: I would have thought that this is a case where you want an array of words, not three distinct variables.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you're doing this in a loop, but all three checks have `i==1` so that means you'll only go into one of these blocks one time. (when `i` is 1).

Normally when you have the same check (logically AND'd) in an entire `if`/`else if` conditional block you can just pull it out of the block:

```
if (i == 1){
   //do all the other checks
}
```

But think about if that's what you really want to do... based on your description of what you're trying to solve, I don't think you need to check for `i` at all.

If you read what you wrote in this SO question the code actually emerges from that:

> if TextA has nothing in it then write word to TextA
>   if TextA does have something in it, write word to TextB
>   And if TextB has something in it, set TextC to word

So the code that follows that logic:

```
if (strlen(TextA) == 0)       // if TextA has nothing in it,
    strcpy(TextA, word);      // then write word to TextA
else if (strlen(TextB) == 0)  // else (if TextB doesn't have anything in it)
    strcpy(TextB, word);      // write word to TextB
else                          // if TextA and TextB already have something
    strcpy(TextC, word);      // then write word to TextC
```

Comment: That won't work because they may come in repeated values.  For example, I could have three As in a row and then a B.

Comment: Still working on debugging this.  Anyone have any tips on how to approach this?  I need to finish this very soon.

Comment: @user2055216 - Ok, your requirements aren't totally clear to me. Can you give an exact example of what you expect during each iteration of the loop. What are the real variable names you're using? When do you store a word in "TextX"? You said not just because it's empty so... what tells me to store it in B and not A or C?